# Unable to retrieve templates in angular unit tests for directives with karama, grunt, and yeoman-maven-plugin

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, maven, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I'm in a less than ideal situation where I need to work with both grunt and maven within a single build.  My directory structure looks like the following:

```
project
+-src
| +-main
|   +-webapp
|     +-app
|       +-css
|       +-js
|         +-commonDirectives.js
|       +-partials
|         +-directives
|           +-address.html
| +-test
|   +-webapp
|     +-app
|       +-js
|         +-commonDirectives.spec.js
+-yo
  +-Gruntfile.js
  +-bower.json
  +-package.json
```

**commonDirectives.js**

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    var commonDirectivesModule = angular.module('commonDirectives', []);

    commonDirectivesModule.directive('ccAddress', [ function() {

        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            scope : {
                address : '=value'
            },
            templateUrl : 'partials/directives/address.html'
        };
    } ]);


}(angular));
```

**commonDirectives.spec.js**

```
(function() {

    "use strict";

    describe('commonDirectives', function() {
        var elm, scope;

        // load the module
        beforeEach(module('commonDirectives'));


        describe('ccAddress', function() {

            beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
                elm = angular.element('<cc-address id="myAddress" value="address"></cc-address></dd>');

                scope = $rootScope;
                $compile(elm)(scope);
                scope.$digest();
            }));


             it('should bind the content with 1 address line', function() {
                var contents = elm.find('cc-address');

                expect(contents.text()).toBe('');

                scope.$apply(function() {
                  scope.address = {
                    line1: 'line 1',
                    city: 'City',
                    state: 'ST',
                    zipCode: '12345',
                    country: 'US'
                  };
                });

                expect(contents.text()).toBe('');
              });

        });

    });
})();
```

Maven builds the java (and ultimately the war), but it delegates to grunt (via `yeoman-maven-plugin`) to run csslint, jshint, can javascript unit tests.  Things are running and tests are successful except when I started writing tests for my directives.  The error I am currently seeing is

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET partials/directives/address.html
```

Based on what I read in [SyntaxError: Parse error problem, provided solutions don't seem to work](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/karma-users/VtW4PLe97O8), the problem is that the paths don't match up.  Grunt is being called from the `yo` directory, so the correct path to the HTML is `../src/main/webapp/app/partials/directives/address.html` but my directive specifies the `templateUrl` as 'partials/directives/address.html'.

How do I make them match?  Or is there something different I should do?

Comment: can you please show the code what you have written to mock your directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was resolved with two parts.  The first is described here: [Karma 'Unexpected Request' when testing angular directive, even with ng-html2js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22873000/388006)

I needed to use the `ng-html2js` plugin to karama to generate javascript file for each of the templates.  More instructions can be found here: [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor configuration](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor#configuration).

For my project I made the following changes to my karma configuration:

```
basePath: '../../',//config file is located in yo/config


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  //lib file reference removed for brevity
  'src/main/webapp/**/*.js',
  'src/main/webapp/**/*.html',
  'src/test/webapp/**/*.spec.js'
],

// generate js files from html templates
preprocessors : {
     //tells plugin which files to process
    'src/main/webapp/**/*.html': "ng-html2js" 
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    //strips the path off so cache keys are correct
    stripPrefix: 'src/main/webapp/app/', 
    //module to load in tests
    moduleName:'templates' 
},
```

Secondly, I needed to load the template module generated by the `ng-html2js` plugin, so I updated `commonDirectives.spec.js` to the following

```
    // load the module
    beforeEach(module('commonDirectives'));

    // load the templates
    beforeEach(module('templates'));
```

Once those two parts were configured correctly, I have had no further problems.