# Cannot test directive scope with mocha

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, mocha.js

I have a simple directive with an isolated scope that I'm trying to test. The problem is that I cannot test the scope variables defined in the `link` function. A watered down sample of my directive and spec below.

**Directive:**

---

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', [function(){
  return {
      scope: {},
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      link: function link(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.screens = [
          'Screen_1.jpg',
          'Screen_2.jpg',
          'Screen_3.jpg',
        ];
      }
  };
}]);
```

**Spec**

---

```
describe.only('myDirective', function(){

  var $scope, $compile;
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_, $httpBackend){
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'template.html').respond();
  }));

  function create(html) {
    var elem, compiledElem;
    elem = angular.element(html);
    compiledElem = $compile(elem)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
    return compiledElem;
  };

  it('should have an isolated scope', function(){
    var element = create('<my-directive></my-directive>');
    expect(element.isolateScope()).to.be.exist;
  });
});
```

---

According to what I've been reading online, this should be working. So after hours of research>fail>repeat I'm leaning to think that it's a bug or a problem with my source code versions. Any ideas?

**NOTE** I'm testing with `Angular 1.2.17`, `jQuery 1.11.0`, `Karma ~0.8.3`, and latest `Mocha`

---

**UPDATE 9/19**
I updated my directive above, for simplicity's sake I had written down an inline template, but my actual code has an external `templateUrl`.  I also added an `$httpBackend.when()` to my test to prevent the test from actually trying to get the html file.

I noticed that inlining the template makes everything work fine, but when I use an external template it doesn't fire off the `link` function.

---

**UPDATE 9/19**
I integrated `html2js`, and now I am able to actually load up the templates from cache and trigger the `link` function. Unfortunately, `isolateScope()` is still coming up `undefined`.

Comment: Works for me with jasmine http://plnkr.co/edit/TJpvgj?p=preview

Comment: Updated my question, it works fine with an inline template, but my actual code has an external templateUrl.

Comment: I tweaked his plunkr with your updated code and it works just as well.

Comment: @Vadim The plunkr is using jasmine, I'm regarding as to mocha.

Comment: So what's the behavior in mocha? Does it create the directive. Are there errors?

Comment: @Vadim `islateScope()` is undefined. I also verified that the `link` function never gets executed.

Comment: Yeah I can't seem to get it working with mocha either. Here's the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/a9jBJw91NUD10NkX1xDr?p=preview How married are you to mocha, since jasmine clearly works.

Comment: Mainly because our Node backend is tested with Mocha. I wish we were using Jasmine since there is so much more documentation on it as well.

Comment: @Vadim solved this by setting up `ng-html2js`. Now I can access the scope by doing `element.isolateScope().myVariable`. The key is to properly setting up the html preprocessor for karma. thanks for your input

Comment: Ah yes, gotta love it when you have to add random stuff to your code to accommodate some test library failure. Glad you got it working :)

Comment: I'm new to testing, so at least it's a great way to break into things and get some experience on how everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue as me, below is the solution.

In **MOCHA**, if you're using external html templates for you directives, you must use the [ng-html2js preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) which will cache all your templates in a js file. Once you have this setup, karma will read these instead of trying to fetch the actual html file (this will prevent the `UNEXPECTED REQUEST: GET(somepath.html)` error).

After this is properly set up. You directive `link` function or `controller` scope will be available to your test via `isolateScope()`. Below is the updated code:

### **Spec**

---

```
describe('myDirective', function(){

  var $scope, $compile;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(module('ngMockE2E')); // You need to declare the ngMockE2E module
  beforeEach(module('templates')); // This is the moduleName you define in the karma.conf.js for ngHtml2JsPreprocessor

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_){
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $compile = _$compile_;
  }));

  function create(html) {
    var compiledElem,
    elem = angular.element(html);
    compiledElem = $compile(elem)($scope);
    $scope.$digest();
    return compiledElem;
  };

  it('should have an isolated scope', function(){
    var elm = create('<my-directive></my-directive>');
    expect(elm.isolateScope()).to.be.defined;
  });

});
```

---

**NOTE** I ran into issues where I still got the `UNEXPECTED REQUEST: GET...` error after I thought I had everything set up correctly, and it turned out that my cached files had a different path than the actual file being requested, look at this post for more help:

[Karma 'Unexpected Request' when testing angular directive, even with ng-html2js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22869668/karma-unexpected-request-when-testing-angular-directive-even-with-ng-html2js)

Comment: Can you take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366791/angular-js-load-json-file-directive-test-failing-mocha